# Segmented linear fit in for loop

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

I've been trying to put the [segmented](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/segmented/segmented.pdf) package in R through a for loop, but I get an error that is related to the `psi` component and I cant resolve. need help.

Here is how I set up the frame work:

```
library(segmented)
data <- read.csv("C:/Users/LM-SEAWIFS.csv")
graphpath <- "C:/Users/testing/"
```

The data looks like this:

```
regions year    chla
NB-0-30 1998    0.130515091
NB-0-30 1999    0.140724909
NB-0-30 2000    0.135240833
NB-0-30 2001    0.138993817
NB-0-30 2002    0.163052182
NB-0-30 2003    0.121473367
NB-0-30 2004    0.143750958
NB-0-30 2005    0.119260133
NB-0-30 2006    0.139529473
NB-0-30 2007    0.125892445
NB-0-30 2008    0.143278167
NB-0-30 2009    0.119866363
NB-0-30 2010    0.1535188
SB-0-30 1998    0.154147909
SB-0-30 1999    0.149347182
SB-0-30 2000    0.146571583
SB-0-30 2001    0.130977867
SB-0-30 2002    0.139928364
SB-0-30 2003    0.126726222
SB-0-30 2004    0.133419183
SB-0-30 2005    0.119234256
SB-0-30 2006    0.134467273
SB-0-30 2007    0.137653236
SB-0-30 2008    0.154858143
SB-0-30 2009    0.124391663
SB-0-30 2010    0.137880678
```

Basically its a `.csv` and I want to fit both linear and segmented model into each plot and save it. The idea is that the For loop will use the `regions` column in the `.csv. file to categorize the data and fit the above regressions to its associate data.

Here is the For loop:

```
for (region in unique(data$regions)) {
    ok<-lm(data[data$regions == region, "chla"]~data[data$regions == region, "year"])
    x <- data[data$regions == region, "year"]
    o.seg<-segmented(ok,seg.Z=~data[data$regions == region, "year"],psi=2007)
    fn <- paste0(graphpath, region, ".png")
    png(filename= fn, width=7, height=3.2, units="in", pointsize=10, res=300)
    plot(data[data$regions == region, "year"], data[data$regions == region, "chla"], xlim=c(1998,2010), ylim=c(0.08,0.2), main = paste(region, "Kd490"), xlab="Time(year)", ylab="Kd490")
    points(data[data$regions == region, "year"],broken.line(o.seg,link=FALSE)$fit,col=2,pch=20)
    #plot(o.seg, add=T, col="red")
    abline(ok, col="blue")
    dev.off()
}
```

This is the error:

```
Error in segmented.lm(ok, seg.Z = ~data[data$regions == region, "year"],:`psi' should be a list with more than one covariate in `seg.Z'
```

I even tried to give the `psi` variable a single integer (like 2007) that is in the data range, but I get the same message. Seems like I have problem in giving it a list.

If I comment out parts of the code related to `segmented`, the loop runs fine and five me all the plots with linear fits.

Or is it the way I assign the `x` and `y` to the `segmented` line?

Comment: The examples in `help("segmented")` clearly show how to pass a `list` to the parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen the help section before, and I tried to pass an argument similar to `seg.Z` to the `psi`, but got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

This demonstrates the correct syntax:

```
region <- "SB-0-30"
ok <- lm(chla ~ year, data = data[data$regions == region,])
o.seg <- segmented(ok, seg.Z = ~year, psi = list(year = 2007))
```

Note how this uses the `data` argument of `lm`.